# Reinitialize/Restart Google Map Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an application in which deals with online/offline situations. 
Right now, I have some instances in which the application is first ran offline, and the api fails to load, which resulted in a blank map page.

The calling of the google map api would be something like this.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY"></script>
```

I have already added an event listener which deals with online/offline situations which is something like this

```
document.addEventListener("offline", function()
{
    console.log("in offline event listener");

}, false);

document.addEventListener("online", function()
{
    console.log("in online event listener");

}, false);
```

How do i check whether my google map api has been initialized and how do i reinitialize it?

Update 1:
I'm able to insert script in runtime via,

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.setAttribute("src", "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
```

But this will cause multiple instances of google map api call in result in my other map plugins fail to work. Thus, I would still need to either destroy the failed map api call or check whether is the google map api is already successfully called and retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of restarting the script, you can try running it only when you have internet connection.

Remove the `<script>...</script>` element from index.html

At your main page javascript:

```
key = "YOUR GOOGLE MAP API KEY"

GoogleMapInit(key);

function GoogleMapInit(key){
  if (key != null){
    apiKey = key;
  }

  loadGoogleMaps();
}

function loadGoogleMaps(){
  window.mapInit = function(){
    //Run any code that must be run after Google Map Api is done (E.g loading markers)
  }

  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.id = "googleMaps";

  if (apiKey){
    script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=' + apiKey + '&callback=mapInit';
  }
  else{
   script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?callback=mapInit';
  }
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

You can also refer to: https://www.joshmorony.com/part-3-advanced-google-maps-integration-with-ionic-and-remote-data/